# ¿Cómo puedo realizar la siguiente tabla mediante el ingreso de un número cualquiera desde una caja de texto con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, tablas

1.- Desarrollar una función en JavaScript que genere una secuencia, dado un numero (N) ingresado por usuario en una caja de texto y además generar una tabla con (N) filas y una columna con los (N) primeros elementos de la secuencia "1", "131", "13531", "1357531", "135797531", ...

Ejemplo con N=5

1

131

13531

1357531

135797531

(Debe estar en una tabla con margenes simples)

2.- Incluir un botón que permita guardar la información generada en el punto anterior como lista de nodos sobre Firebase.

Este es el código:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        document.querySelector('#btngenerar').addEventListener('click', function(){

            numero = document.querySelector('#txtnumero').value;

            var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
            var cero = document.getElementById("cero");
            var vacio = document.getElementById("vacio");

            var tabla;

            if (numero === ''){
                vacio.innerHTML = 'No ha ingresado ningún numero';
            }

            if (numero == "0"){
                cero.innerHTML = 'El numero que ingresó es 0';
            }

            do {

                var a = 1;
                var b = 2;

                for(i = 1; i <= numero; i++){

                    tabla = a + b;

                }


            } while (numero > 0);


            resultado.innerHTML = tabla  ;

        })
    })
</script>
```

```
<h3>Generación de tabla según número ingresado</h3>
<label for="">Ingrese el número que desee: </label>
<input type="text" id="txtnumero">
<button id="btngenerar">Generar</button>
<table> 
    <tr><td><div id="resultado"></div></td></tr>
</table>
<p id="cero"> </p>
<p id="vacio"> </p>
```

Comment: Hola Aldrín, puedes compartir lo que tienes pensado hacer o lo que ya tengas hecho? así es más fácil ayudarte. Por otro lado, para mejorar el formato de tu pregunta y así aumentar las posibilidades de poder ayudarte, te recomiendo que revises la página de ayuda sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos!!

Comment: Hola Mario, como podrás haber apreciado soy nuevo en el portal ¿Te puedo adjuntar en un hilo de comentario el código que tengo hecho hasta el momento?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes aplicarlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
//Este es el javascript (dentro de la etiqueta "script") que ejecuta toda la lógica:
function genera(){
    var cantidad = document.getElementById("txtNum").value;
    var cadena = "";
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    //obtengo los impares y los voy concatenando:
    for(var i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++){
        var impar = (2*i)-1;
        cadena = cadena + impar;
    }//hasta aquí tengo los primeros N impares que componen la secuencia final (para N = 5 tendría: 13579)

    //ahora obtengo los impares en orden descendente para completar la secuencia final:
    for(var i = cantidad-1; i > 1; i--){
 var impar = (2*i)-1;
 cadena = cadena + impar;
    }//hasta aquí completo la secuencia final (para N = 5 tendría: 135797531)
  
    //Aquí es donde creo la tabla y voy colocando en cada fila, la secuencia correspondiente:
    //Para ello voy recorriendo la secuencia final para ir formando las secuencias anteriores
    //Y las voy colocando en cada celda de la tabla:
    for(var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
 var cad = cadena.substring(0,i+1);
 var x = cad.length;
   var cadenaInvertida = "";
   while (x>=0) {
         cadenaInvertida = cadenaInvertida + cad.charAt(x);
            x--;
        }
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        var text = document.createTextNode(cad.slice(0,-1) + cadenaInvertida);

        td.appendChild(text);
        tr.appendChild(td);

        table.appendChild(tr);
     }
     document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
/*Aquí le das estilo a la tabla (dentro de la etiqueta "style")*/
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Finalmente el Html donde ingresas el número de secuencias a generar -->
Cantidad: <input type="text" id="txtNum">
<button onclick="genera()">GENERAR</button>
```

Esto sería la primera parte, si tienes alguna duda coméntala; espero te ayude.